# Flex align-items: stretch not working on button element in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, flexbox

Using `align-items: stretch` on a `<button>` in Chrome seems to not work. It works fine in Firefox.

See an example here:
https://jsfiddle.net/y8a2qoef/4/

`stretch` works fine when the container/flex-element is a `<div>` but not when it's a `<button>`

I wanted to post this here in case I'm missing something; maybe the spec says somewhere it's not supposed to work on `<button>`'s and Firefox is just being nice. Otherwise, it looks like this is a Chrome bug?

Comment: Considering this even works in IE, I'd have to call it a chrome bug.

Comment: Okay I'm gonna report it.

Comment: The answers to the "duplicate" question are very useful and related, but the question itself isn't really a duplicate, because this question is specifically about the "stretch" value, while that question is about the "center" value (which works fine in Chrome).

Comment: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1004163

Comment: @V.Rubinetti, the duplicate shows that `button` elements reject changes to the `display` value in some browsers. This means that `display: flex` and flex properties, such as `align-items`, are ignored. So the values, whether `stretch` or `center`, are irrelevant.